# Parsing HTML using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, html-parsing

I need help in parsing a HTML file. I'm new to C# and LINQ and everything i tried has not been successfull in extracting the "link" and the "Name 1"

```
     <tr class="Row">
              <td width="80">
                <div align="left"> <a href="link">details</a>
                </div>
              </td> 
              <td width="152">Name 1</td> 
              <td width="151">Name 2</td> 
              <td width="152">Name 3</td> 
              <td width="151">Name 4</td> 
              <td width="151">Name 5</td> 
              <td width="152">Name 6</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="Row">
              <td width="80">
                <div align="left"> <a href="link">details</a>
                </div>
              </td> 
              <td width="152">Name 1</td> 
              <td width="151">Name 2</td> 
              <td width="152">Name 3</td> 
              <td width="151">Name 4</td> 
              <td width="151">Name 5</td> 
              <td width="152">Name 6</td>
      </tr>
```

This is what i tried:

```
                var links = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.Name == "tr")
                    .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "Row")
                    .Select(x => x.Descendants()
                    .Where(s => s.Name == "href"));

                foreach (var link in links)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(link);
                }
```

Comment: Are you using Html Agility Pack?

Comment: I'm using HtmlAgilityPack-PCL

Comment: check the answer and tell me if something is not clear

Comment: .Where(s => s.Name == "href") should be 
.Where(s => s.Name == "a" && a.Attributes["href"]!=null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nodes= htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.Name == "a" || 
(n.Name == "td" && n.Attribute["width"] != null && n.Attribute["width"].Value != "80" && n.Parent.Name == "tr" && n.Parent.Attribute["class"] != null && n.Parent.Attribute["class"].Value = "Row"));


                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    if(node.Attribute["href"] != null)
                    {
                         Debug.WriteLine(node.Attribute["href"].Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
                    }
                }
```

You need something like this. You are taking every node with name a or every `td` node which width is not 80 and the `tr` parent node have `class="Row"`

Answer (score 0):

Your linq doesn't reflects the html's stucture.
It can be simply achieved using [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

```
 var links = htmlDoc.DocumentElement
    .SelectNodes("//tr[class='Row']/td/div/a")
    .Select(aElem=>aElem.Attributes["href"].Value)
```

Comment: I can't use Xpath because my project is Windows Phone 8.1